# Providing subcommands to a command executed with SSH.NET

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

I've created a simple app which uses the Renci.SshNet library to update firewall configuration on my Fortigate device.

```
var auth =
    new AuthenticationMethod[] { new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password) };
ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo(server, 22, username, auth);

sshclient.Connect();

string command;
string addressname = "testaddress";

command = "config firewall address";
output.Add(command);
output.Add(sshclient.CreateCommand(command).Execute());

command = string.Format(@"edit {0}", addressName);
output.Add(command);
output.Add(sshclient.CreateCommand(command).Execute());

sshclient.Disconnect();
```

I get the following from the output:

```
config firewall address
fw1 # fw1 (address) # 
edit testaddress
fw1 # Unknown action 0 fw1 #
```

The same commands work fine over a normal SSH connection.

```
fw1 # config firewall address
fw1 (address) # edit testaddress
new entry 'testaddress' added
fw1 (testaddress) #
```

Just wondering if I'm using it correctly sending separate `CreateCommans.Execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the `edit testaddress` is a subcommand of the `config firewall address` command.

While your code executes it as a separate top-level command.

You have to feed the `edit testaddress` subcommand to the input of the `config firewall address` command. But SSH.NET unfortunately does not support providing an input with the `CreateCommand` interface.

You have to open a shell session (what is otherwise a not recommended approach for automating a command execution).

Use `SshClient.CreateShellStream` or `SshClient.CreateShell` and send the commands to its input:

```
"config firewall address\nedit testaddress\n"
```

For a sample code see [C# send Ctrl+Y over SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52775498/850848).