# Providing subcommands to a command (sudo/su) executed with SSH.NET SshClient.CreateShellStream

Tags: c#, .net, shell, ssh, ssh.net

I am trying to use Renci SSH.NET to connect to a remote Linux server from a C# web application and execute shell scripts. I want to run the scripts one after another. But not getting how to run the scripts and read the output and store it in a label.
I have tried the below code, but not able to pass multiple commands one line after another.

```
SshClient sshclient = new SshClient("host", UserName, Password);
sshclient.Connect();
ShellStream stream = sshclient.CreateShellStream("commands", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);
```

```
public StringBuilder sendCommand(string customCMD)
{
    StringBuilder answer;

    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.AutoFlush = true;
    WriteStream(customCMD, writer, stream);
    answer = ReadStream(reader);
    return answer;
}

private void WriteStream(string cmd, StreamWriter writer, ShellStream stream)
{
    writer.WriteLine(cmd);
    while (stream.Length == 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

private StringBuilder ReadStream(StreamReader reader)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        result.AppendLine(line);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am trying to run the below commands

```
sudo su - wwabc11
whoami
cd /wwabc11/batch/bin/
pwd
```

How to run the commands one after another and read the output information? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the "commands" to the `StreamWriter`.

```
writer.WriteLine("sudo su - wwabc11");
writer.WriteLine("whoami");
// etc
```

See also [C# send Ctrl+Y over SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52775498/850848).

---

Though note that using `CreateShellStream` ("shell" channel) is not the correct way to automate a commands execution. You should use `CreateCommand`/`RunCommand` ("exec" channel). Though SSH.NET limited API to the "exec" channel does not support providing an input to commands executed this way. And `whoami` and the others are actually inputs to `sudo`/`su` command.

A solution would be to provide the commands to `su` on its command-line, like:

```
sudo su - wwabc11 -c "whoami ; cd /wwabc11/batch/bin/ ; pwd"
```

For an example of code that uses `CreateCommand` to execute a command and reads its output, see see [SSH.NET real-time command output monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31587924/850848).