# Providing input/subcommands to a command (cli) executed with SSH.NET SshClient.RunCommand

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, ssh.net, juniper

I created a program using Renci SSH.NET library. Its sending all the commands and reading the result normally. However, when I send the command below:

```
client.RunCommand("cli");
```

The program hangs on this line indefinitely.

Any explanation of what is happening?

The `cli` is a command is used on Juniper switches/routers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, `cli` is a kind of a shell/interactive program. So I assume you have tried to do something like:

```
client.RunCommand("cli");
client.RunCommand("some cli subcommand");
```

That's wrong. `cli` will keep waiting for subcommands and never exit, until you explicitly close it with a respective command (like `exit`). And after it exits, the server will try to execute the `cli subcommand` as a separate top-level command, failing too.

---

You have to feed the "cli subcommand" to the input of the `cli` command. But SSH.NET unfortunately does not support providing an input with the `SshClient.RunCommand`/`SshClient.CreateCommand` interface. See [Allow writing to SshCommand](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/802).

---

There are two solutions:

- Use the appropriate syntax of the server's shell to generate the input on the server, like:

  ```
  client.RunCommand("echo \"cli subcommand\" | cli");
  ```
- Or use a shell session (what is otherwise a not recommended approach for automating a command execution).

  Use `SshClient.CreateShellStream` or `SshClient.CreateShell` and send the commands to its input:

  ```
  "cli\n" + "cli subcommand\n"
  ```

  For a sample code see [Providing subcommands to a command (sudo/su) executed with SSH.NET SshClient.CreateShellStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54194139/850848) or [C# send Ctrl+Y over SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52775498/850848).

Comment: Thanks. ShellStream works perfectly fine in case of subcommands