# How to using Ssh.net to run a command "sudo ufw delete 3" and give a next command "y"?

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I need to execute the delete IP command ("sudo ufw delete 3") but after sending Ssh.net's RunCommand or CreateCommand & Execute, there will be no response and let me execute the next step, so I can't execute the command Y to delete, if I use putty it is It can be done by executing y after executing sudo ufw delete 3.
By the way, is it possible to delete the specified IP.

```
string _host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
string _username = "root";
string _password = "xxxxx";
int _port = 22;
SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(_host,_port,_username,_password);
if (!sshClient.IsConnected)
{
    sshClient.Connect();
}
SshCommand sshCmd = sshClient.RunCommand($"sudo ufw delete 3");   <--- no response
sshCmd = sshClient.RunCommand($"y");
sshClient.Disconnect();
sshClient.Dispose()
```

I have test RunCommand on

```
SshCommand sshCmd = sshClient.RunCommand($"sudo ufw allow from {_IP} to any port 22");
```

This can work.But it doesnt need press "Y"

Comment: See also [Providing input/subcommands to a command (cli) executed with SSH.NET SshClient.RunCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57666090/850848).

Comment: Side notes: `sshClient` needs a `using` to dispose it correctly, and you should probably consider using `async` `await`

Comment: NB: (1) I did not try it, but if this host/username/password combination is a real one, you just shared your root password with the world. I suggest you change it ASAP. (2) If you log in as root, there's no need to use sudo.

Comment: Hey if `runcommand()`  no getting response can it setting the timeout ? Does it use `ConnectionInfo.Timeout` ?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl if use like "sudo ufw delete 3" to RunCommand and no response is there any way to give a timeout to run out of the code and give a timeout , because i try to add  
 `sshClient.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);` it doesn't work , by the way this problem is i want to avoid the command that users use incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending "y", just tell `ufw` [not to ask for confirmation](https://serverfault.com/q/790143/17182):

```
sudo ufw --force delete 3
```

---

Do note, though, that what you are doing is **quite dangerous**: You delete the third firewall rule, *whatever that rule may be*. Unless you are *absolutely sure* that the rule currently at the third position is the one you want to delete, you seriously risk removing some random rule and either opening a security hole in your firewall or locking yourself out.

A better alternative would be to refer to the rule *by content* rather than by number, e.g.

```
ufw delete allow 443     # removes the rule that allows access to port 443
```

Comment: It is work ! Thanks for help @Heinzi , This way i would call  an api to do so ,and  add jwt token to avoid security problem .

Answer (score 0):

I think there're 2 ways to do it, get the one you're interested in:

1. echo "y" | sudo ufw delete 3
2. yes | sudo ufw delete 3

Try that and let met know.
Greetings.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,i try to use `SshCommand sshCmd = sshClient.RunCommand($"echo y");` And `sshCmd = sshClient.RunCommand($"sudo ufw delete 3");`  , is still no response on second command.

Comment: What's not what ItzDC2 has suggested you to do. Though the solution by @Heizi is better anyway.

Comment: I meant you to do something like this: SshCommand sshCmd = sshClient.RunCommand($"echo 'y' | sudo ufw delete 3").
You need the pipe operator in the same query.
I also think like @MartinPrikryl, the Heinzi's answer is better than mine.

Comment: Thanks @ItzDC2 for give me another suggest i will try later and give you answer, i will use the better way to run my code .

Comment: @ItzDC2 the echo 'y' this way is works ! Thanks for help.